# How to add auto-notification and reporting functionality to a SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint, notifications

I have recently created a list on our team's SharePoint site for tracking the list of action items for the team on a real-time basis and subsequently working to connect it with Excel for report generation. I wanted to add a few more functionalities but, am unable to understand how to go about it. The list of functionalities is as shared below -

1. Send auto-notification to assigned people in the action item list for all items overdue on a weekly basis.
2. Send auto-notification to assigned people in the action item list once the deadline for closure (as indicated in the list) is within 15 calendar days on a weekly basis.
3. Send a auto-summary report to the designated team managers on a weekly basis indicating the list of items overdue and pending for closure in next 7 calendar days.

Any help and guidance on how to add these functionalities to our existing SharePoint list will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I am not a SharePoint Developer but, have interest in the topic. I do not have any coding experience. I have been trying to experiment with the tool to reduce some of our mundane activities and hence, wanted to check with the experts if the above functionalities are actually possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these functionalities, I would suggest you build scheduled flow to send notifications evety week.

[image]